# Trigonometry solutions without calculator

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos x =\frac{\sqrt{5} +1}4$ where x is in radians  results in one solution of $x=\frac\pi5$, how do I prove this without the use of a calculator.

similarly if $\tan x = 2 +\sqrt{3}$ and $x$ is $0<x<\frac\pi2$ find without the use of a calculator the exact value of $x$

Comment: Trig without calculators? That's very hard and it would be unlikely that you would be asked this question without context or trig tables.

Comment: It is practically impossible to understand what  "(5^1/2+1)/4" **actually** means...though one could guess it is $\;\frac{5^{1/2}+1}4\;$ ...but it could we be wrong, too.  You better use MathJaX, or at the very least use more parentheses to make your intention crystal clear...

Comment: Sorry this is my first ever question on this site it is intended to be as you have suggested. I can prove tan 75 = 2 + 3^1/2 and am wondering if i can do the question in reverse. ie given tanx = 2+3^1/2 can I find the exact value of x without a calculator

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi5.html

Comment: It's tedious, but not difficult to find radicals for the trig ratios for 3°. Good luck doing it for 1°. :D

Answer (score 2):

In general, there isn't an exact analytic expression for the inverse trigonometric functions of an arbitrary radical.

Only a handful of small rational multiples of $\pi$ have trig functions that can be expressed using simple rational number and radicals. Sure, you can extend those a little with half-angle formula & addition and subtraction rules, but you soon run into horrible nested radicals, and for multiples of $\pi/n$ for $n>5$ you're generally dealing with equations that don't *have* solutions that can be expressed as radicals, as proven by the [Abel–Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

The same logic applies going in the reverse direction. Given a trigonometric ratio written as some arbitrary radical expression there generally isn't an exact analytic expression involving multiples &/or radicals of $\pi$ which is the inverse function of that ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$2+\sqrt3=\csc30+\cot30=\cdots=\cot15$$

If $4\cos x=\sqrt5+1,5=(4\cos x-1)^2$

$$4\cos^2x-2\cos x-1=0$$

Now see http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54090.html